# Swift - UIWebView - This application is modifying the autolayout engine

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

I am trying to embed a youtube video in a `UIWebView` the code I have works fine however, every time I play the video and the video players opens I get a warning:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.
>   Stack:(     0
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181e96dc8  +
>   148   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001814fbf80
>   objc_exception_throw + 56     2   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000181e96cf8  + 0     3   Foundation
>   0x0000000182947b2c  + 88    4   Foundation
>   0x00000001827c8c3c  + 36    5   UIKit
>   0x00000001870fcd98  + 64    6   UIKit
>   0x00000001870fd8b0  + 244   7   UIKit
>   0x000000018788b7f0  + 268   8   UIKit
>   0x0000000187308aa0  + 176   9   UIKit
>   0x0000000186ff01e4  + 656   10  QuartzCore
>   0x0000000184982994  + 148   11  QuartzCore
>   0x000000018497d5d0  + 292   12  QuartzCore
>   0x000000018497d490  + 32    13  QuartzCore
>   0x000000018497cac0  + 252   14  QuartzCore
>   0x000000018497c820  + 500   15  WebCore
>   0x0000000186b56270  + 176   16  WebCore
>   0x0000000186b18fa4  + 368   17  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000181e4d09c  + 24    18  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000181e4cb30  + 540   19  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000181e4a830  + 724   20  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000181d74c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384     21  WebCore
>   0x0000000185d6261c  + 456   22  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x0000000181afbb28  + 156   23  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x0000000181afba8c  + 0     24  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x0000000181af9028 thread_start + 4 )

The Code I use is:

```
    let string = "<html style='margin:0;background:black;'><body style='margin:0;background:black;'><iframe style='position:absolue;top:0;left:0;margin:0;' width='\(webViewWidth)' height='\(webViewHeight)' src='\(src)' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
   webViewYT.loadHTMLString(string as String, baseURL: nil)
```

Looking online I found out that I have to encapsulate UI changes in a dispatch_async.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your issue that a) you have tried executing `loadHTMLString` on the main thread using `dispatch_async` but it doesn't work, or b) that you don't know how to implement `dispatch_async` to run on the main thread, or c) something else?

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to remove the warning